# Avoid code repetition in two different classes toString

Tags: java, oop

Modeling a solution just to display(in console) the `FreeCell` card game,
I have two classes **Home** and **FreeCells**, both way almost similar `toString` implementation

output something like this

```
+----+----+----+----+
| 2♣ | E  | E  | E  |
+----+----+----+----+
```

#### class Home

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Home {
    private final int MAX_CELLS = 4;
    private Stack<Card>[] homeCells;

    public Home() {
        this.homeCells = new Stack[4];
    }


    public boolean addACard(Card card) {
        //...some code
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder box = new StringBuilder();
        box.append(buildHorizontalBorder());
        box.append("\n");
        box.append(buildContent());
        box.append("\n");
        box.append(buildHorizontalBorder());
        return box.toString();
    }

    private String buildContent() {
        StringBuilder contentBox = new StringBuilder();
        contentBox.append("|");
        for (int index = 0; index < MAX_CELLS; index++) {
            contentBox.append(" ").append(this.homeCells[index] == null ? "E " : this.homeCells[index].peek().toString()).
                    append(" ").append("|");
        }
        return contentBox.toString();
    }

    private String buildHorizontalBorder() {
        StringBuilder border = new StringBuilder();
        border.append("+");
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CELLS; i++) {
            border.append("----").append("+");
        }
        return border.toString();
    }
}
```

#### class FreeCell

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FreeCells {
    private final int MAX_CELLS = 4;
    private List<Card> cells;

    public FreeCells() {
        this.cells = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public boolean addCard(Card card) {
        //...some code
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder box = new StringBuilder();
        box.append(buildHorizontalBorder());
        box.append("\n");
        box.append(buildContent());
        box.append("\n");
        box.append(buildHorizontalBorder());
        return box.toString();
    }

    private String buildContent() {
        StringBuilder contentBox = new StringBuilder();
        contentBox.append("|");
        for (int index = 0; index < MAX_CELLS; index++) {
            contentBox.append(" ").append(index < this.cells.size() ? this.cells.get(index).toString() : "E ").append(" ").append("|");
        }
        return contentBox.toString();
    }

    private String buildHorizontalBorder() {
        StringBuilder border = new StringBuilder();
        border.append("+");
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CELLS; i++) {
            border.append("----").append("+");
        }
        return border.toString();
    }
}
```

I am thinking of introdcuing a new class and abstract out the display logic to here

#### class Layout

```
public class Layout {
    private final int MAX_CELLS = 4;


    public String build(List<Card> cards) {
        StringBuilder box = new StringBuilder();
        box.append(buildHorizontalBorder());
        box.append("\n");
        box.append(buildContent(cards));
        box.append("\n");
        box.append(buildHorizontalBorder());
        return box.toString();
    }
    

    private String buildContent(List<Card> cards) {
        StringBuilder contentBox = new StringBuilder();
        contentBox.append("|");
        for (int index = 0; index < MAX_CELLS; index++) {
            contentBox.append(" ").append(index < cards.size() ? cards.get(index).toString() : "E ").append(" ").append("|");
        }
        return contentBox.toString();
    }

    private String buildHorizontalBorder() {
        StringBuilder border = new StringBuilder();
        border.append("+");
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CELLS; i++) {
            border.append("----").append("+");
        }
        return border.toString();
    }
}
```

Then change the method of `toString` of class **Home** to

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new Layout().build(Arrays.stream(this.homeCells).filter(Objects::nonNull).map(Stack::peek).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
```

Then change the method of `toString` of class **FreeCell** to

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return new Layout().build(this.cells)();
}
```

Is this correct OO way, or i can do this better some other way?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because reviews of working code are off topic here.

Comment: Having said that: you might turn to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ... but remember: read their help center content carefully before asking a question there. Ensure to not repeat your mistake and coming up with off topic content.

Comment: Having said that: from a first glance, your code looks good. The only thing you *could* change: your methods in the layout class, they don't share any information (you have no fields in that class, besides your constant). Thus you could consider to make the methods static. Keeping it non-static only makes sense if there is a reasonable chance that you will want to use different Layout classes (based on inheritance or so) later on.

Answer (score 0):

In my view, we can separate logic of game from cards:

- `FreeCellGame` class will be responsible for logic of game.
- `Cell`, `FreeCell` and `HomeCell` will be responsible for cards.

We can extract the same logic of `FreeCell` and `HomeCell` in base class `Cell`. I mean methods `toString()` and `buildHorizontalBorder()`. I do not know Java, so I will show in C#. However, I will make comments how it can be converted to Java:

```
public abstract class Cell
{
    private int MAX_CELLS = 4;

    public abstract bool AddCart();

    // When you add some card, you need to remove
    // card from array where you took this card
    public abstract bool RemoveCart(Card card);

    public string toString() {
        StringBuilder box = new StringBuilder();
        box.Append(buildHorizontalBorder());
        box.Append("\n");
        box.Append(buildContent());
        box.Append("\n");
        box.Append(buildHorizontalBorder());
        return box.ToString();
    }

    internal abstract string buildContent();

    private string buildHorizontalBorder() {
        StringBuilder border = new StringBuilder();
        border.Append("+");
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CELLS; i++)
        {
            border.Append("----").Append("+");
        }
        return border.ToString();
    }
}
```

and its concrete implementations:

```
public class HomeCell : Cell // ":" extends in Java
{
    // other code is omitted for the brevity 
    
    public override bool AddCart()
    {  }

    public override bool RemoveCart(Card card)
    {  }

    internal override string buildContent()
    {  }
}

public class FreeCell : Cell // ":" extends in Java
{
    // other code is omitted for the brevity 
    
    public override bool AddCart()
    {  }

    public override bool RemoveCart(Card card)
    {  }

    internal override string buildContent()
    {   }
}
```

and game class is:

```
public class FreeCellGame
{
    private HomeCell homeCell = new HomeCell();
    private FreeCell freeCell = new FreeCell();

    private void AddCard()
    { 
        // your logic of game here
        // here you will manipulate by calling methods of "homeCell" and 
        // "freeCell" to move cards from their arrays
    }
}
```